# LWJGL Drawing colored text to the screen issue

Tags: java, text, colors, lwjgl

I am trying to display text on the screen and eclipse is telling me that the drawString method does not accept a Color variable.  This is my code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont;

public class Text {

static TrueTypeFont font;

public static void drawText(int x, int y, String text) {

    Font awtFont = new Font("Terminal", Font.BOLD, 24); 
    font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false);
    font.drawString(x, y, text, Color.yellow); //x, y, string to draw, color
}

}
```

And this is how I call the method.

```
Text.drawText(10, 10, "randomText");
```

It is saying that I am not allowed to put Color.yellow, can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong.  This is the error that I get if I try to run it with the color.  Note that if I take away the Color it does draw it on the screen.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method drawString(float, float, String, Color) in the type TrueTypeFont    
is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, String, Color)
```

Also if anyone could give an example of how to make a method that takes an z, y, String, and a Color that would help me a lot.

Comment: Slick 2d has it's own Color class, you should use that. [Javadoc](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Color.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to change your import to `import org.newdawn.slick.Color` or use
`font.drawString(x, y, text, org.newdawn.slick.Color.yellow);`